# PHP script as single binary

Tags: php, release-management

I was whatching facebook's development steps and getting codes live , i think they are making their script as a single binary and pushing a single file. We got a portal with alot of files inside which coded with PHP . is there any encoder or compiler can bundle all files in single one ?

While we are pushing our codes to our servers when renaming folder or extracting files and override , it starts to give error spam.

Also any  solution or approach to send the webpages alive without getting any error are welcome.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FaceBook use a tool named [HipHop](https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/wiki/) which compiles PHP into a single binary executable.

Comment: @wpearse: the same story with me and Thrift

Comment: yes that was the thing what i look for thanks, hope 5.3 support comes fast.

Comment: not handy ? , just wondering how to switch applications when you push a release to live. i mean application runs as webserver as well so users connected to that servers will get a conn reset when you make a new release thought.

Comment: @KevinLee, maybe. Don't forget that users open a connection to FB, read the webpage, then close the connection. So unless the user is actually in the process of downloading a webpage they won't see the connection reset. FB probably has a whole bunch of fancy load balancers/routers so they can take a few servers offline, perform the upgrade, put the servers back online again, and rinse and repeat...

Answer (score 2):

You probably need [PHAR](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.phar.php)

Comment: + oned - Hadn't thought of that way of using it, I'd have to try that!

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, Linux and FreeBSD there's [Roadsend PHP Compiler](http://www.roadsend.com/home/index.php?pageID=compiler).  It truly compiles PHP source code into native binary format.  No interpreter is required.

They claim: "Roadsend PHP is a free, open source implementation of the PHP language. It includes a compiler that produces native binaries (no interpreter required). Roadsend Compiler can build online web applications with Fast/CGI, offline web applications with an embedded web server (MicroServer), and console applications."

They say: "Applications compiled with the Roadsend Compiler do not require Zend or any other interpreter to execute. Roadsend is not affiliated with Zend or the PHP Group and does not share (nor is it derived from) the same code base as their PHP implementation. Roadsend PHP is an entirely new implementation of PHP that is syntactically and semantically compatible with PHP Group's PHP 5.2.x and the Zend Engine 2." – Sebastián Grignoli 41 secs ago edit

"How do I know that my application won't be decompiled back to the PHP source file?"

"The compiling of a PHP application with the Roadsend Compiler is much the same as compiling a C file to binary format. The program goes through a process that converts the plain text source into a binary format that is suitable for the processor to execute, and which is extremely hard to decompile back to any sort of high level programming language."

Comment: **Native binary**!? Don't believe.

Comment: It's a serious, well known project, that stands on the LLVM Compiler Infrastructure ( http://llvm.org )

Comment: It is not possible that any code can be compiled. Like: `eval(file_get_contents('file.php'));`. To evaluate this code you **need** php interpreter. PS: oh " Roadsend PHP is an entirely new implementation of PHP" --- so it is just an interpreter + sources packed in one binary?